# jxl.read.biff.BiffException: The input file was not found

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

URL: http://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist_xls/RNGWHHDd.xls
Program:

```
 URL url = new URL(Url);
 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
 InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
 Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(in);
```

I get **input file not found exception** even though the url mention the corrected formated excel file. Any suggestions?

Comment: save that content and open with any reader.

Comment: see this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know if this help, i have `BiffException` too, and the problem was that  the excel was closed incorrectly in my program, i tried to create again and it works.. hope it helps.

Comment: I changed the url from http to https and it worked. Thanxs